# How to change the font on styles.css

Tags: magento-1.9, fonts

I found out that the font is on `styles.css` using the inspect mode(ctrl+shift+i), but when I change it and upload it via FileZilla and refresh the page it stills the same font as before, I'm completely new to this so be very specific please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure you flush the cache**.

**Using the Admin Panel**

1. Log in to your Magento Admin Panel.
2. From the System tab, click Cache Management.
3. Click Flush Magento Cache. If successful, you will see the message, “The Magento cache storage has been flushed.”

**Using SSH**
You must have SSH access to your server in order to use this method.

After you log in to your server, run the following command from your site’s root folder:

```
php -r 'require "app/Mage.php"; Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();'
```

If you still can't see the change, it could be your browsers cache too so view the webpage in  incognito mode or clear browsers cache.

Still nothing? View source of HTML and just make sure that the page is using the CSS file you modified.

Comment: Great! I'm glad :)